# CVS file List in list Python

Tags: python, list, loops, csv

I have a CVS file with the following list. I am trying to check for a certain date from this list and then read the value.

```
[
 ['"2020-10-01"', '0', '4', '0.4', '6.8', '10.3', '11.9', '4.5', '7.2', '7.6', '13.8', '0.9', '9.8']
 ['"2020-10-02"', '0.1', '4.4', '2.6', '7.8', '10.1', '11.8', '4.4', '7', '7.4', '13.6', '0.8', '9.7']
 ['"2020-10-03"', '0', '4.9', '2.3', '7.2', '10', '11.6', '4.2', '6.9', '7.2', '13.4', '0.6', '9.5']
 ['"2020-10-04"', '1.1', '4.8', '1.8', '7.6', '9.8', '11.4', '4.1', '6.7', '6.9', '13.3', '0.5', '9.4']
]
```

This is what I have tried

```
for row in List:
    for srow in row[0]:
        if date in srow:
        print(date[1])
```

Comment: what is `date` ?

Comment: the first row of each list represent the date.

Comment: So your code isn't working ? Where is stored the *certain date* you're looking for ? Please improve the details

Comment: for example if user search of the first date in the list 01.10.2020.

Comment: Why aren't you answering my question, not at all ? I'm asking where is `date` defined in you code, and why is there extra double quote around the dates ?

Comment: for srow in row[0]: i guess

Answer (score 0):

The following answer assume there is no double quotes around the date.

You need to get the searching date from somewhere, user input for example, then you need to search for inclusion in the row, don't iterate over `row[0]` this iterates over the chars of the first element

```
date = input("Please give a date: ")
List = [
    ['2020-10-01', '0', '4', '0.4', '6.8', '10.3', '11.9', '4.5', '7.2', '7.6', '13.8', '0.9', '9.8'],
    ['2020-10-02', '0.1', '4.4', '2.6', '7.8', '10.1', '11.8', '4.4', '7', '7.4', '13.6', '0.8', '9.7'],
    ['2020-10-03', '0', '4.9', '2.3', '7.2', '10', '11.6', '4.2', '6.9', '7.2', '13.4', '0.6', '9.5'],
    ['2020-10-04', '1.1', '4.8', '1.8', '7.6', '9.8', '11.4', '4.1', '6.7', '6.9', '13.3', '0.5', '9.4']
]
for row in List:
    if date in row:
        print(row)

# DEMO
Please give a date: 2020-10-01
['2020-10-01', '0', '4', '0.4', '6.8', '10.3', '11.9', '4.5', '7.2', '7.6', '13.8', '0.9', '9.8']
```

Comment: Not of help. Thank you for trying

Comment: @Leke don't understand your message^^

Answer (score 0):

Just modify '"yyyy-mm-dd"' to  'yyyy-mm-dd' and now it works:

```
mylist = [['2020-10-01', '0', '4', '0.4', '6.8', '10.3', '11.9', '4.5', '7.2', '7.6', '13.8', '0.9', '9.8'],\
 ['2020-10-02', '0.1', '4.4', '2.6', '7.8', '10.1', '11.8', '4.4', '7', '7.4', '13.6', '0.8', '9.7'],\
 ['2020-10-03', '0', '4.9', '2.3', '7.2', '10', '11.6', '4.2', '6.9', '7.2', '13.4', '0.6', '9.5'],\
 ['2020-10-04', '1.1', '4.8', '1.8', '7.6', '9.8', '11.4', '4.1', '6.7', '6.9', '13.3', '0.5', '9.4']]



example_date = '2020-10-02'

for row in mylist:
  if row[0] == example_date:
      print('Found in: ' + str(row))
      break
```